# StaticLayout get number of displayed characters

Tags: java, android, canvas

I write a book reader. For the correctly display text on my pages, I need to know, How many characters can be on display ?

```
TextPaint mTextPaint=new TextPaint();
      mTextPaint.setTextSize(16);

      StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(newText, mTextPaint, canvas.getWidth() - 20, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.5f, 0.0f, false);
      canvas.save();


      int x = 10, y = 50;
          y += p.ascent() + p.descent();

          canvas.translate(x, y);

          mTextLayout.draw(canvas);
          canvas.restore();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to get last visible line. You can get it with Layout.getLineForVertical method.
After that you can get text offset for line with methods Layout.getLineEnd/Layout.getLineVisibleEnd

Example:

```
int line = mTextLayout.getLineForVertical(canvas.getHeight()); // position of last visible line
int chars = mTextLayout.getLineEnd(line);
```